# send encoded array cause 'The URI you submitted has disallowed characters'

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I want to send array in url to class function in other php file. That function will process the data in the array and produce the output. I encode the array before send.

```
$array=array("Volvo", "BMW", "Toyota");
$encode=json_encode($array);
echo "<a class = 'btn btn-primary' href='".base_url()."index.php/dashboard/generate_list_in_excel/".$encode."'>List in excel</a>";
```

But, I could not send the encoded array successfully. I got this error.

> The URI you submitted has disallowed characters.

I already try to replace `$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\-';` with `$config ['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%[].:\_\=+%\&';` in config.php. Still have this error.

Answer (score 0):

Try with [http_build_query()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php)

```
    $array = ["Volvo", "BMW", "Toyota"];
    
    $url = base_url() . "index.php/dashboard/generate_list_in_excel/?" . http_build_query($array);

// url would be test.com/index.php/dashboard/generate_list_in_excel/?0=Volvo&1=BMW&2=Toyota

    echo "<a class = 'btn btn-primary' href='" . $url . "'>List in excel</a>";
```

Then to get the params use [parse_url()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php):

```
$params = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_QUERY);
```

Comment: I got this error when try this way. `Too few arguments to function Dashboard::generate_list_in_excel()`

Comment: well you're calling your method without passing the any params(arguments) ... I suppose you have something like - function generate_list_in_excel($params) { .... Now with your link you call your method, but you dont pass anything as argument. What you can do -

Answer (score 0):

When you want to send data in the url, use a query string instead:

```
index.php/some-url?someKey=someValue
```

and then get that data using $_GET:

```
$data = $_GET['someKey'];
```

When passing data in the URL, you should always encode the data using [urlencode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php)

```
?someKey=<?= urlencode($theData) ?>
```

#### Alternative

Instead of passing json, you can create a query string out of that array. Then you won't need to json encode and decode the data. Let's use [http_build_query()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) to create the query string for us.

```
// Start by wrapping your current array in another array with a key
// so it's easier for us to fetch the data from the query string
$array = ['data' => ["Volvo", "BMW", "Toyota"]];

// Create the query string
$query = http_build_query($array);

// Append it to your URL (note that we added ? before concatenating the query string)
echo "<a class = 'btn btn-primary' href='".base_url()."index.php/dashboard/generate_list_in_excel/?" . $query . "'>List in excel</a>";
```

Now you can get the data with:

```
$data = $_GET['data'];
```

which will now contain the array.

Comment: I got this error when try alternative method. `Too few arguments to function Dashboard::generate_list_in_excel()`. generate_list_in_excel is a method. I am passing the array to that method for processing

Comment: @Premlatha - That's sounds like a completely different problem. Let's focus on one issue at the time. If any of the answers you got to the posted issue, please mark it as accepted. If none solved the issue you posted about, then you need to explain why so we can fix it. If get a different issue, you need to post a new question about that specific problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use implode to change array into string, send it in URL, then on backend use explode to make array again

```
$array=array("Volvo", "BMW", "Toyota");
$encode=implode(',',$array);
//die();
echo "<a class = 'btn btn-primary' href='".$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."index.php/dashboard/generate_list_in_excel?array=".$encode."'>List in excel</a>";
```

use of explode

```
$data = $_GET['array'];
$str_arr = explode (",", $data);  
print_r($str_arr); 
?>
```

Comment: I receive this error `Not allowed to load local resource:`.

Comment: `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` will return an absolute file system path, not a URL (which is what the href needs.)